# Unix Script : I want to print only the XML Message from the log file

Tags: xml, unix

Unix : I am having a log file which consists of text message and xml message. I want to print only the xml message based on my unique value in xml.
Is that possible?

Prior and End of XML, there was a text.

Sample Log Message:

```
04-21-2017 22:44:42,265|INFO|[Timer-1]|[SYZ Project]|[com.xyz.abc]|- Some text message  
04-21-2017 22:44:42,269|INFO|[Timer-1]|[SYZ Project]|[com.xyz.abc]|- Publishing the record :: <XmlTag1  cursor="value1"><XmlTag2>value2</XmlTag2>......<XmlTagn>valuen</XmlTagn> </XmlTag1>  
04-21-2017 22:44:42,274|INFO|[Timer-1]|[SYZ Project]|[com.xyz.abc]|- Some text message
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Do you want to only print the XML part, or the whole line which contains XML? Do  you want to only print in case the special value "valuen" is inside, or any XML message? Please take the [tour], you might find useful hints on formatting in the help center.

Comment: Thanks Yunnosch. I want to print one complete XML based on Unique value namely primary identity.  That Log File have set of 70 -80 XML File repeated. I dont need all that. Hope this clears your query.